# Why do Kubernetes' containers fail when ran on runsc (gVisor) as a runtime in Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, kubeadm

I am running a single master Kubernetes cluster with Docker. I wanted to try runsc (gVisor) on Kubernetes. I just wanted to start each container in a separate sandbox. So I set runsc as the default runtime and restarted the Docker service. To my surprise, all the Kubernetes' containers were failing (checked with `docker ps`). What is the exception that causes this? Is there any other way to use gVisor+Docker+Kubernetes?

I am using the right requirements to run each of them.

PS: I am just a beginner.

Comment: Try to update your question by following this: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note: it is advisable to lurk on Stack Overflow so you can respond to comments promptly. You received some excellent feedback some nine minutes after posting, and around four hours later, the post is still unchanged, and gathering close votes. It can be easier to respond now, rather than waiting for a question to close and then editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying gVisor!  Sorry it isn't working for you.

Running a Kubernetes Pod inside gVisor is still fairly experimental.  It can be made to work, but is a bit difficult to configure right now.  We are working to make this easier.

Can you run gVisor with Docker (not Kubernetes)?  See the instructions here:
https://github.com/google/gvisor#configuring-docker

If that fails, please file a bug report:
https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues

If you can include debug logs, that will help us diagnose any failure.
https://github.com/google/gvisor#debugging